# Internal "get/set" function of property?

Tags: python, panel

Here is my test code and picture:

```
import bpy


# Simple property reading/writing from ID properties.
# This is what the RNA would do internally.
def get_float(self):
    return self["testprop"]


def set_float(self, value):
    self["testprop"] = value

#bpy.types.Scene.test_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(get=get_float,set=set_float)
bpy.types.Scene.test_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty()


bpy.context.scene.test_float = 12.34
```

[image]

When I don't explicitly set the "get/set" function for my property, after assigning the value, I can get the property value by 'scene["test_float"]', but if I explicitly set the "get/set" function, then if I try to type in the same commands, I will receive a error "KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "test_float" not found'" . So what should I do to get the same results by using explicitly 
"get/set" function?

Comment: you could simply retrieve the value using `bpy.context.scene.test_float` instead of looking it up with the `bpy.context.scene["test_float"]` syntax. This works in both cases for me.

Answer (score 8):

**It's named "testprop" not "test_float"**

When a property defined via

```
bpy.types.Scene.test_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(...)
```

is assigned a value `scene.test_float = value`  it is stored. "behind the scenes" as a custom property `scene["test_float"]`  (*"second time above"*)

In the get / set example (*"first time above"*) it is instead stored in a custom property named "testprop".

Instead, had  the custom property been named "test_float" in the getter and setter, it would emulate the behaviour of the float property without a getter and setter, and be reflected in the value and existence of `scene["test_float"]` when set.

Perhaps this needs to be an edit in [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.props.html?highlight=floatproperty#get-set-example) re what RNA would do internally.

Note if the getter is defined thus

```
def get_float(self):
    return self.get("test_float", 0.0)

def set_float(self, value):
    self["test_float"] = value

bpy.types.Scene.test_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(get=get_float,set=set_float)
```

it will return a default value, in this case `0.0` even if the property has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

use self.testprop. the property exists this is just if you use self['testprop'] the self is refering to the local context and is not able to update the dict further. I guess the dict should be passed in argument to use self['testprop']