# Is There a Way to Change a Prop with an Update Def without Calling the Update Def?

Tags: python

Is there a way to change a prop with an update def without calling the update def?

```
def update_prop(self, context):
    print ("update")
    if self.variable > 10:
        self.variable  = 10 #10 is a variable that changes in my code 
    #i want to set the prop without recalling the update
    else:
        print("else")



class Props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):


    bpy.types.Object.variable  = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="variable",
        default=0,
        min=0,
        update=update_prop,
```

Comment: Please make the question more clear and concise.

Comment: Could you please put a little more effort into your questions?

Comment: @metaphor_set better ?

Comment: A lot better, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, simply setting a max will do this for us

```
import bpy

def update_prop(self, context):
    print ("update")
    print(self.variable)


bpy.types.Object.variable  = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name="variable",
    default=0,
    min=0,
    max=10,
    update=update_prop)
```

In python console

```
>>> C.object.variable = 22
update
10

>>> C.object.variable
10
```

If you wish to set a value and not fire an update, set the id property.  A property defined via `bpy.props` for example `ob.prop` is stored as `ob["prop"]` once set to non default.

May  be better to use a getter / setter method(s)  [Internal "get/set" function of property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property/134310#134310)

```
def update_prop(self, context):
    print ("update")
    self["variable"] = 4
    print(self.variable)


>>> C.object.variable = 22
update
4

>>> C.object.variable
4
```

*Note this has been answered recenlty, couldn't find that one*