# How to loop values on Custom properties

Tags: looping

I added a custom property to an object with an integer value and a max of 3. Is there any way to loop the value? I want it to return to the value of **0** after **3**. Is it possible?[image]

[image]

Comment: With a custom property `ob["switch"]` not so easy... with a `bpy.types.Object.switch = bpy.props.IntProperty` imagine its doable.  Is this how you have defined the prop?

Comment: Could you drive it from another custom property, using a scripted expression such that switch = input%3?

Answer (score 1):

**Setter / Getter and modulus.**

[image]
*Zoomed in test. Can see 4 pop up when holding mouse down and sliding, but the setter turns 4 to 0*

[Internal "get/set" function of property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property/134310#134310)

[How can I change IntProperty default value stored within PropertyGroup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195459/how-can-i-change-intproperty-default-value-stored-within-propertygroup)

[Is There a Way to Change a Prop with an Update Def without Calling the Update Def?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135025/is-there-a-way-to-change-a-prop-with-an-update-def-without-calling-the-update-de/135167#135167)

If we set up an int property with a getter and setter can assure it remains in a certain range.  For this case have set the min to 0 and max to 4, but if the property is set to 4 it reverts to zero, using the modulus operator

```
value = value % 4
```

*ie* the integer remainder when divided by four.  This is stored in the file as a custom property emulating how properties work.

Set the default value in the getter, I've used 0

Test Code.

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import IntProperty

def get_int(self):
    return self.get("test", 0)

def set_int(self, value):
    self["test"] = value % 4

bpy.types.Object.test = IntProperty(
    min=0,
    max=4,
    get=get_int,
    set=set_int,
    )
    
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    ob = context.object
    layout.prop(ob, "test")

# tacked onto object props transform panel to test.    
bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_transform.prepend(draw)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm still a beginner at scripting, I guess I'll need to learn more :)