# How to declare global variables for use in an addon that aren't stored in the blend file

Tags: python, add-on

How can i cleanly declare and edit variables for use in an addon the don't need to be registered like a PropertyGroup but also aren't stored in the blend file?

I'm working off of the basic addon structure like so:

```
def boolPropVarAccess(self, context):
    # Test accessing a 'global' variable declared at some other point in the addon structure

class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False,
        update=boolPropVarAccess
        )


class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool


        # Declare some 'global' addon variable like an object reference

        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool")

        layout.separator()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    MyProperties,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The window manager**

If you set up properties on the window manager using `bpy.props` they are available globally for the session, are not saved and revert to defaults on next.  PRO: simple to add a UI, a lot of UI for operators uses `wm`.

```
>>> bpy.types.WindowManager.foo = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=444)
>>> wm = C.window_manager
>>> wm.foo
444

>>> wm.foo = 3
```

**The driver namespace**

The driver namespace can be leveraged.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x

dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns["var"] = Foo(3)
```

then anywhere

```
global_var = dns.get("var") # None if not set
```

**Make a module**

```
from my_module import my_global_variable
```

**Declare a global**

```
max_something = 10000

def update(self, context):
    global max_something
```

Using lists and dictionaries here often removes the need for the `global` declaration.

**Getter Setter on bpy.props**

In example in question code, if using a global instead of using update would set up properties with a get set method. See docs.

As in this example, [Internal "get/set" function of property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property)

let the `get` or `set` methods retrieve or set your global respectively.  The `set` method is akin to an update in this scenario.

Example of saving to a text file to avoid undo operations.

[How can I avoid Undo/Redo on StringPropery or bpy.props in general?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223197/how-can-i-avoid-undo-redo-on-stringpropery-or-bpy-props-in-general/223498)

Comment: Hello could you please describe how to `set up properties on the window manager using bpy.props`?

Comment: The driver namespace just works properly !