Blender progress bar not updating while downloading file
I wrote a function and an operator to download files, but whenever I am downloading the files, Blender freezes. and progress bar is not updating, while downloading, it is only updated after the download finished.
I Imported threading, for this, download is working fine, the only issue is with freezing blender and updating progress bar realtime.
# Global variable to store download progress
download_progress = 0.0
is_downloading = False

# Lock for thread-safe progress updates
progress_lock = threading.Lock()

# Function to download a file in a background thread
def download_file(url, save_path):
    global download_progress, is_downloading

    with progress_lock:
        is_downloading = True

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))

        if response.status_code == 200 and total_size > 0:
            downloaded = 0

            # Open a file to write the download stream
            with open(save_path, 'wb') as file:
                for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                    file.write(data)
                    downloaded += len(data)

                    # Update progress inside the download loop
                    with progress_lock:
                        download_progress = downloaded / total_size
                        bpy.context.scene.download_progress = download_progress  # Update scene progress
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Error downloading asset: {response.status_code}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during download: {e}")

    finally:
        with progress_lock:
            download_progress = 1.0  # Mark the download as complete
            bpy.context.scene.download_progress = 1.0
            is_downloading = False  # Reset downloading flag

I wrote this operator to download files and save them in a directory
class DownloadAssetOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "asset_browser.download_asset"
    bl_label = "Download Asset"

    file_name: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    _timer = None
    _thread = None

    def execute(self, context):
        
        try:
            prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences
            id_token = prefs.id_token  # Fetch the id_token stored during login

            # Check if the user is logged in (if id_token exists)
            if not id_token:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Please log in first.")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

            # Get the asset directory from preferences
            asset_directory = prefs.asset_directory

            # Ensure the directory exists
            if not os.path.exists(asset_directory):
                os.makedirs(asset_directory)

            # print(f"ID Token: {id_token}")

            # Step 1: Get assetId using file_name
            asset_id = get_asset_id(self.file_name, id_token)

            # Step 2: Get presigned URL using assetId
            presigned_url = get_presigned_url(asset_id, self.file_name, id_token)

            # Step 3: Download asset with progress bar
            save_path = os.path.join(asset_directory, self.file_name)

            # Start the download and update the progress bar
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(presigned_url, save_path))
            self._thread.start()

            # Start a modal timer to update the progress in the UI
            self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)

        except Exception as e:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, str(e))

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        global download_progress, is_downloading

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            with progress_lock:
                # If download is in progress, update progress bar in 3D view header
                if is_downloading:
                    # Redraw the 3D View header
                    for area in context.window.screen.areas:
                        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                            area.tag_redraw()
                            # Force a redraw of the header
                            for region in area.regions:
                                if region.type == 'HEADER':
                                    region.tag_redraw()
                else:
                    self.finish(context)
                    return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
    def finish(self, context):
        # Remove the timer and stop modal operator
        context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Download Complete")
        print("Operator finished")  # Debug: print when operator finishes
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Start the modal operator
        return self.execute(context)

and also a panel to view progress bar
class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        global download_progress, is_downloading
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Progress here:")
        layout.prop(bpy.context.scene, "download_progress", slider=True)

Progress bar FloatProperty is registered, in the register function in the bottom of the code
bpy.types.Scene.download_progress = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Progress", default=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)

What could be the issue, where am I wrong?
Update:
# Global variables to store download progress
download_progress = 0.0
is_downloading = False
download_complete = False

# Lock for thread-safe progress updates
progress_lock = threading.Lock()

def download_in_background(url, save_path):
    global download_progress, is_downloading, download_complete
    is_downloading = True
    download_complete = False
    download_progress = 0.0

    try:
        # Start the download request
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))
            chunk_size = 1024  # 1 KB
            downloaded_size = 0

            with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
                        downloaded_size += len(chunk)
                        
                        # Update progress safely with the lock
                        with progress_lock:
                            download_progress = (downloaded_size / total_size) * 100

            # Mark the download as complete
            with progress_lock:
                download_complete = True
                download_progress = 100.0
        else:
            print(f"Failed to download the file. HTTP Status: {response.status_code}")
            with progress_lock:
                download_complete = True  # Mark as finished even if failed

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during download: {e}")
        with progress_lock:
            download_complete = True  # Mark as finished even if failed

class DownloadAssetOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "asset_browser.download_asset"
    bl_label = "Download Asset"
    
    file_name: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    _timer = None
    _thread = None

    def execute(self, context):
        prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences
        id_token = prefs.id_token

        if not id_token:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Please log in first.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        asset_directory = prefs.asset_directory
        if not os.path.exists(asset_directory):
            os.makedirs(asset_directory)

        asset_id = get_asset_id(self.file_name, id_token)
        presigned_url = get_presigned_url(asset_id, self.file_name, id_token)

        save_path = os.path.join(asset_directory, self.file_name)
        
        # Start download in a separate thread
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=download_in_background, args=(presigned_url, save_path))
        self._thread.start()

        # Start the progress timer to update Blender's UI without freezing
        bpy.app.timers.register(self.update_progress)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def update_progress(self):
        global download_progress, download_complete

        with progress_lock:
            # Update progress in Blender's progress bar
            bpy.context.window_manager.download_progress(download_progress / 100.0)

            if download_complete:
                self.finish()
                return None  # Stop the timer, download is complete

        # Return a time interval to re-call this function (to update regularly)
        return 0.1  # Update every 0.1 second

    def finish(self):
        bpy.context.window_manager.progress_end()  # End the progress bar
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Download Complete")
        bpy.context.scene.download_progress = 1.0  # Ensure the progress is set to 100% when done
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.window_manager.progress_begin(0, 100)  # Start progress bar
        return self.execute(context)

Now Blender is not freezing, and also the file is downloading, but, Progress bar is still not updating with the download?

Might be related: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-when-using-the-threading-module See other stuff on the page as well.

Not sure global variables just work like that in Blender add-ons. Try storing stuff some other way. Search for a good way to do this with Blender API here on BSE. Maybe this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160451/how-to-declare-global-variables-for-use-in-an-addon-that-arent-stored-in-the-bl ?..

The problem is the entire download process happens within one iteration of the modal operator, after the with open file as .... You want to find another way to do it, store the result of the request somewhere and throttle the download in every modal execution

"I wrote[...]" - you or chat GPT?
