# Force scientific notation in Blender GUI

Tags: python, customization

I have an addon in development, and create various meshes in it. I have several physically based parameters, that are often extremely small, but make sense in the context they are. I have in my GUI class, for example:

```
poly_0: FloatProperty(
        name="POLY_0",
        description="Some description...",
        default=1.26587922531743e-16,
        min=-1000.0,
        max=+1000.0,
        )
```

In the GUI, I would like to force this Float member to always be displayed in scientific notation, and always with some set precision (number of digits). Looking in the API docs, I cant seem to find this option.

Comment: AFAIK setting the `precision` argument to `6` (max) is the only thing you can do...

Comment: @brockmann, very valuable information. I thought the precision of FloatProperty was per default 64bit, as with python floats. When you wrote 6 as display-preciscion max, I looked up the documentation. It does state that it is single precision [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FloatProperty.html). This puts my addon development in trouble. I am going to ask a new question about this instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Make a Scientific Notation Property Group.**

As a workaround could set up a property group to handle scientific notation. Restricted to the significant digits of the float property, but allows to set the the power.

Here I've used a generic python property with getter and setter. can do same with `bpy.props.` properties and expose to the UI.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, IntProperty, PointerProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from math import pow, log10, floor

class ScientificNotation(PropertyGroup):

    def set_num(self, value):
        self.power = floor(log10(abs(value)))
        self.number = value / pow(10, self.power)
        
    def get_num(self):
        return self.number *  pow(10, self.power)
    number : FloatProperty(min=-10, max=10)
    power : IntProperty()
    value = property(get_num, set_num)

bpy.utils.register_class(ScientificNotation)
bpy.types.Scene.foo = PointerProperty(type=ScientificNotation)
```

Layout with both number and power to set. Use the value property in calculation.  *Could use a string property for the number, to get more sig digits.*

**[image: strong text]**

Example of use in python console.

```
>>> C.scene.foo.number = 6.62607004
>>> C.scene.foo.power = -34
>>> C.scene.foo.value
6.626070022583007e-34

>>> C.scene.foo.value = -344233.44e-44
>>> C.scene.foo.value
-3.442334413528442e-39

>>> C.scene.foo.number
-3.4423344135284424

>>> C.scene.foo.power
-39
```

Can add pythonic methods as well, *eg* `repr` or `str`

```
class ScientificNotation(PropertyGroup):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value :6e}"
```

to

```
>>> C.scene.foo
3.442334e-39
```

See also  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134310/15543

Comment: is there a way to have multiple instances of the ScientificNotation class in a menu? Right now I'm having to specify separate classes, as otherwise the value from one shows up as the suggested for another in a different part of the menu. Is there some kind of PropertyGroup collection I could use to avoid that pattern?