# How to assign FloatProperty, EnumProperty etc values through script

Tags: python

I have been googling this and can't find an answer.
I defined a float property that creates a number spinner in my UI that allows me to move an object back and forth. I would like to clamp this value dynamically so I can't use the built-in FloatProperty clamp values. The code below should work, yet it seems to reset the value to the default value when it should get clamped.

```
def SetPos(self, context):
    self['left'] = Clamp(self['left'],0,1)

def register():
    bpy.types.Object.left = FloatProperty(name="left", default=0.34, unit="LENGTH", update=SetPos)
```

Another issue is that I don't see how to change an enumproperty through script. I can see in the python console it just assigns the string value to the prop like
`bpy.context.object.myEnum = 'BLA'`
but when I do an assignment like that myself, the UI does not update.

Comment: Hello, could you post your  `Clamp` method ?

Comment: Also, why don't you use the `min` and `max` fields of the properties ?

Comment: Setter / getter example. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134310/15543  see also the _RNA_UI dictionary of a custom prop, which can be dynamically altered if not in use when not currently defined as a `bpy.props` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update method will be invoked every time you try to modify the value of this property, like a callback function. The manual do warn about infinite loop when your update method constantly do something to props.

As your code, each time you update a new value, you **set** the value instead of **check the value then** set. So each time you invoke update method, blender **will trigger another** update function since you "set" value that is supervised by Blender system.

Not sure how to avoid this behavior but you might check the condition first then change the value:

```
def SetPos(self, context):
    if need_clamp(self['left']):
        self['left'] = Clamp(self['left'],0,1)
    # so next time this method will do nothing
```

Or just use setter and getter function:
[Property Definitions (bpy.props) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#getter-setter-example)

Comment: I don't have a problem with the clamp function. Perhaps I should change the title of the post. The problem I have is that I don't understand how to set the values of 'Properties' (float, enum bool etc) without causing arecursion error and while having the UI update to reflect the changed state.

Comment: Did you mean update UI? I thought there is a method that you can called directly to let Blender refresh UI component: [Force UI/custom property refresh/update - Coding / Python Support - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/force-ui-custom-property-refresh-update/621586)

Comment: And also, the setter function should accept a self and a value, which will be clamped. [Force UI/custom property refresh/update - Coding / Python Support - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/force-ui-custom-property-refresh-update/621586). In your scenario, setter function will be better than update perhaps?