# Need code review. Get and Set understanding

Tags: python

What I have:

select two points then click “First” (get length between), then other two points - click “Second” (get length between), and then click “Scale” and get value “Second / First”.

Am I right with code, or somewhere it can be simplified?
[image]

```
import bpy

import bmesh
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel, PropertyGroup

def get_float1(self):
    return self["l1"]

def set_float1(self, value):
    self["l1"] = value

def get_float2(self):
    return self["l2"]

def set_float2(self, value):
    self["l2"] = value

def length_first():
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    elem_list1 = []

    for g in bm.select_history:
        elem_list1.append(g)
            
    lf1 = elem_list1[0].co
    lf2 = elem_list1[1].co

    length1 = (lf2 - lf1).length
    print("First value =", length1)
    return length1
    
def length_second():    
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    elem_list2 = []

    for g in bm.select_history:
        elem_list2.append(g)
            
    ls1 = elem_list2[0].co
    ls2 = elem_list2[1].co

    length2 = (ls2 - ls1).length    
    print("Second value =", length2)    
    return length2  


class VERTS_OT_length (Operator):
    bl_idname = "verts.length"
    bl_label = "l"
    bl_description = ""

    action: bpy.props.EnumProperty (
        items=[('first','first',''),
               ('second','second',''),
               ('scale','scale','')])
    
    def execute(self, context):
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        if self.action == "first":            
            props.l1 = length_first()            
        if self.action == "second":
            props.l2 = length_second()
        if self.action == "scale":
            scale = props.l2 / props.l1
            print("----------------------")
            #print(props.l1)
            #print(props.l2)
            print("Scale =", scale)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class LENGTH_PG_main (PropertyGroup):

    l1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Get",
        subtype="DISTANCE",
        get=get_float1,
        set=set_float1
    )
    
    l2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Set",
        subtype="DISTANCE",
        get=get_float2,
        set=set_float2
    )
    
    
class TEST_PT_main(Panel):
    bl_label = "TEST"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'TEST'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        row1 = col.row(align = True)        
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        row1.prop(props, "l1", text="")
        row1.operator("verts.length", text="First").action = "first"
        
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        row2 = col.row(align = True)        
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        row2.prop(props, "l2", text="")
        row2.operator("verts.length", text="Second").action = "second"
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("verts.length", text="Scale").action = "scale"


classes = (
    VERTS_OT_length,
    LENGTH_PG_main,
    TEST_PT_main,
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

def register():    
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

    bpy.types.Scene.LENGTH_PG_main = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = LENGTH_PG_main)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property/134310#134310

Answer (score 1):

so answer is:

1. `def length_first()` and `def length_second()` can be merged in one `def length()`

```
def length():
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    elem_list1 = []

    for g in bm.select_history:
        elem_list1.append(g)
            
    lf1 = elem_list1[0].co
    lf2 = elem_list1[1].co

    distance = (lf2 - lf1).length
    return length
```

2. as @batFINGER sugested

```
def get_float1(self):
    return self["l1"]

def set_float1(self, value):
    self["l1"] = value

def get_float2(self):
    return self["l2"]

def set_float2(self, value):
    self["l2"] = value
```

need to replace with own properties to not get error like `KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "l1" not found'`

The final code for me look like this:

```
import bpy

import bmesh
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel, PropertyGroup

def get_float1(self):
    props  = bpy.context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    return props.dist1

def set_float1(self, value):
    props  = bpy.context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    props.dist1 = value

def get_float2(self):
    props  = bpy.context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    return props.dist2

def set_float2(self, value):
    props  = bpy.context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    props.dist2 = value

def length():    
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    elem_list2 = []

    for g in bm.select_history:
        elem_list2.append(g)
            
    ls1 = elem_list2[0].co
    ls2 = elem_list2[1].co

    length = (ls2 - ls1).length    
    print("Second value =", length)    
    return length  


class VERTS_OT_length (Operator):
    bl_idname = "verts.length"
    bl_label = "l"
    bl_description = ""

    action: bpy.props.EnumProperty (
        items=[('first','first',''),
               ('second','second',''),
               ('scale','scale','')])
    
    def execute(self, context):
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        if self.action == "first":            
            props.l1 = length()            
        if self.action == "second":
            props.l2 = length()
        if self.action == "scale":
            scale = props.l2 / props.l1
            print("----------------------")
            #print(props.l1)
            #print(props.l2)
            print("Scale =", scale)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class LENGTH_PG_main (PropertyGroup):

    dist1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1)
    dist2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1)
    
    l1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Get",
        subtype="DISTANCE",
        get=get_float1,
        set=set_float1
    )
    
    l2: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Set",
        subtype="DISTANCE",
        get=get_float2,
        set=set_float2
    )    
    
class TEST_PT_main(Panel):
    bl_label = "TEST"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'TEST'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        row1 = col.row(align = True)        
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        row1.prop(props, "l1", text="")
        row1.operator("verts.length", text="First").action = "first"
        
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        row2 = col.row(align = True)        
        props  = context.scene.LENGTH_PG_main
        row2.prop(props, "l2", text="")
        row2.operator("verts.length", text="Second").action = "second"
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("verts.length", text="Scale").action = "scale"


classes = (
    VERTS_OT_length,
    LENGTH_PG_main,
    TEST_PT_main,
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

def register():    
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

    bpy.types.Scene.LENGTH_PG_main = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = LENGTH_PG_main)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.LENGTH_PG_main
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Hope it will be useful.